# By Beautifulsoup. I want replace ＜br＞ to line-break : At the time of getText()

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup

I use BeautifulSoup for web-scraping by python.

Issue is "All ＜br＞ tags removed when getText()".

I know getText() function is extract only texts.

But in result, All text became into 1-line, Can't see same as web-site.

**What I want** : "When I use getText(), I want only ＜br＞ tag is **NOT remove**. Just only **replace to** line-break(\n)"

If you have idea, Please help me.

*Sample text ↓*

```
# - This is text of before getText() -------
<dd class="resbody">
<a class="auto" href="/a/Linux">Linux</a>勉強するならCは当然として<br/><a class="auto" href="/a/Python">Python</a>も押さえておかないと<br/>大変になるかなあと感じている。

</dd>

# - This is text of after getText() -------
Linux勉強するならCは当然としてPythonも押さえておかないと大変になるかなあと感じている

# - This is "What I want" after getText() -----
Linux勉強するならCは当然として
Pythonも押さえておかないと
大変になるかなあと感じている。
```

---

*My code is this ↓*

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

resheads = soup.find_all("dt", class_="reshead")
resbodys = soup.find_all("dd", class_="resbody")

formattedHead = []
formattedBody = []
resCount = 0

# 整形済みレスヘッダ部取得
for rhead in resheads:
    h = rhead
    h = h.getText()  # テキスト部分抽出
    h = h.replace('\n', '')  # 不要な改行を削除
    h = h.replace(' ', '')  # 不要な空白を削除
    h = h.replace(')', ') ')  # 整形
    h = h.replace('ID:', ' ID:')  # 整形
    formattedHead.append(h)

# 整形済みレス本体部取得
for rbody in resbodys:
    b = rbody
    b = b.getText() # <-- <br> is removed at here.
    b = b.strip()  # 前後から空白削除
    b = b.strip('\n')  # 前後から改行削除
    formattedBody.append(b)
    # カウントするのはheadでもbodyでもどちらでもいいのだが、この数が本ページにおけるレス数になる(通常は30だが最終ページでは少ない可能性あり)
    resCount += 1
```

FYI(Entire code) : https://github.com/we-yu/sb.webscraping/blob/other/QuestionSrc/nicopedy_saver.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing code in this section

```
for rbody in resbodys:
    b = rbody
    b = b.getText() # <-- <br> is removed at here.
    b = b.strip()  # 前後から空白削除
    b = b.strip('\n')  # 前後から改行削除
    formattedBody.append(b)
    # カウントするのはheadでもbodyでもどちらでもいいのだが、この数が本ページにおけるレス数になる(通常は30だが最終ページでは少ない可能性あり)
    resCount += 1
```

to

```
# 整形済みレス本体部取得
for rbody in resbodys:
    # converting bs4 object to str
    b = str(rbody).replace("<br/>", "\n")  #changed here
    b = BeautifulSoup(b, "html.parser").getText() 
    formattedBody.append(b)
    # カウントするのはheadでもbodyでもどちらでもいいのだが、この数が本ページにおけるレス数になる(通常は30だが最終ページでは少ない可能性あり)
    resCount += 1
```

Comment: Thanks Mr @Dennis I copied your code and kicked. But sorry, At the time of Run, I got error as this.
---
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Documents/python/ncncscrp/nicopedy_saver.py", line 178, in <module>
    resCount, formattedHead, formattedBody = GetAllResInPage(url)
    File "/Documents/python/ncncscrp/nicopedy_saver.py", line 99, in GetAllResInPage
    b = rbody.replace("<br/>", "\n")  # changed here
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
---
Line:99 is
> b = rbody.replace("<br/>", "\n")  # changed here
This line.

Comment: One moment am updating my answer

Comment: Thanks, A lot. Arigatou. <(_ _)>
Excuse me now I try to paste Error code, But all text became 1 line.

Comment: I got it! That is exactly What I wanted!
I understood. I should have convert to `str` replace, then back to `bs4` obj.

Now I can complete my script. Huge thanksful for you!